# Can't add to private ArrayList attribute consisting of objects

Tags: java, arraylist, attr

*The fill method is meant to be called from another class, which has a menu consisting of options, one of which is a fill option.

I am trying to add twenty six huntsingercard objects to an array list of huntsingercard objects outside of the constructor. Oddly enough, I can't seem to accomplish this without using the constructor to fill the array list. I've tried the same thing with arrays and it works just fine, but the fill() method fails to add values onto the list.

```
class huntsingerdeck
{
private ArrayList<huntsingercard> list = new ArrayList<huntsingercard>();

public huntsingerdeck()
{
}
public void fill()
{
    for(int a=0; a<26; list.add(a++,new huntsingercard()));
}
```

What exactly am I missing here? I've also tried instantiating the list in the constructor, but that also messes with the array as well.

Comment: call `fill()` from your constructor, or some other method?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: I'm calling `fill()` from another class where two huntsingerdeck objects have been instantiated. Apologies for the lack of clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with an instance initializer

```
public class HuntSingerDeck {

  private ArrayList<HuntSingerCard> list = new ArrayList<HuntSingerCard>();    

  {
      for(int a=0; a<26; a++) {
          list.add(new HuntSingerCard()));
      }
  }

  public HuntSingerDeck() {
    //Array list is already initialised and filled at this point
  }

}
```

Instance initializers will be fired before the constructor is called when creating a new instance.  This means the arraylist will be filled before reaching the start of the constructor.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I forgot to clarify something. I need to be able to call a fill method from outside of the class... think a menu of options of what to do with an empty card deck.

Answer (score 0):

**Basically your for loop syntax is incorrect, the last expression should be 0 to n arithmetic operations, not boolean (because add() returns boolean)**

So, you need t change it as below (with a++ expression):
Also, as you don't want to use a constructor, you can use instance initializer as shown below:

```
class huntsingerdeck
{
private ArrayList<huntsingercard> list = new ArrayList<huntsingercard>();

public huntsingerdeck()
{
}

{
   fill();
}

public void fill()
{
    for(int a=0; a<26; a++) {
           list.add(new huntsingercard()));
        }
}
```

**for loop syntax:**

```
for (initialization; termination; increment) {
    statement(s) 
  }
```

You can refer [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Comment: although we often see a for loop like you present it it's totally correct to put some code in you increment part try this code `for(int a=0; a<26; System.out.println(a++)) {   }`

Comment: if the loop syntax is incorrect why would be able to compile it?

Comment: @user43968 That's the reason I have mentioned 0 to n arithmetic operations

Comment: my loop is 0 to n arihmetic too ;)

Comment: @Jon I did not go through your answer, was editing parallelly step by step